# GridView CellFormatting Lost Randomly after Refresh

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I am using Telerik RadControls for WinForms Q3 2010 and having an issue with grid control.

**scenario:** I have a grid control in my main form grid control have 20+ columns (Hidden+ Visible) and i am performing Cell Formatting according to my business logic i am facing a strange behavior which is that at certain time i lost cell formatting (see attached image) randomly also when this happened grid becomes un-responsive and application crashed by clicking grid control.my grid refreshes randomly whenever a new record insert

**Edit:**
[image]

Comment: Could you attach your attached image?

Comment: @Seano666 i have attached image now you can see it

Comment: Please show the code where you apply formatting with business logic.